# Android UI forbids valid tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, android-app

I wanted to edit a question on Android but when submitting the edit, the UI complained about my invalid use of tags (NB: I hadn’t even edited the tags).

[image: screenshot]

What an odd check to make. The tag in question, by the way, is [c](/questions/tagged/c) – hardly unconventional. ;-)

Comment: There's also [tag:r], [tag:d] and [a few others](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/165589/get-tags-consisting-of-1-character).

Comment: I’m actually really amused by this bug because it’s so non-obvious: somebody must have made a conscious effort to put this check in without looking whether it actually made sense.

Comment: Perhaps someone put it in to see if the users are paying attention :)

Comment: Well I could see how it might be possible it was just hastily modified stock validation code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed as of version 1.0.8, thanks!